# Эффект перекатывания на css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть картинка на сайте и описание к ней. Нужно чтобы при наведении на это описание картинка менялась на другую, то есть что-то типа анимации было. Как это реализовать? Только учусь, не судите строго.
Знаю что при наведении на картинку так делается:

```css
a.rollover {
  background: url(img/8.png); /* Путь к файлу с исходным рисунком  */
  display: block; /* Рисунок как блочный элемент */
  width: 375px; /* Ширина рисунка */
  height: 651px; /* Высота рисунка */
}

a.rollover:hover {
  background: url(img/9.png); /* Путь к файлу с заменяемым рисунком  */
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" class="rollover"></a></p>
```

А как сделать при наведении на текст чтобы менялись?

Comment: Так анимироваться не будет, надо по-другому...

Comment: @Qwertiy а как можно сделать?

Comment: Хотя стоп. Я вообще вопрос неправильно понял. Ты же анимацию просил вроде? А в приведённом коде никакой анимацией и не пахнет. Как и текстом, про который ты спрашиваешь. В общем, делай [mcve].

Comment: @Qwertiy,  я не знаю как ее сделать. В этом и вопрос) как ее сделать учитывая мой вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы по наведению на описание менялась картинка, надо, чтобы в разметке абзац с описанием шёл ДО блока с картинкой (при этом визуально они могут располагаться как угодно относительно друг друга):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}
p {
  float: right;
}
.pic {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/51720/61d22c75-c500-445c-83ea-1199467ddbbb/s1200');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}
p:hover + .pic {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/49816/82e873bb-d4f4-4864-a59d-dafee5ea8a48/s1200');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>
  Здесь описание картинки<br />
  Здесь описание картинки<br />
  Здесь описание картинки
  </p>
  <div class="pic"></div>
</div>
```